# Name Error when instantiating a class in Python

Tags: python, class, instance, nameerror

Okay, so I'm trying to create a class in Python that assigns parameters to the  elements of the periodic table, using the following code:

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, Symbol, Name, Number, Row, Column):
        self.Symbol = Symbol
        self.Name = Name
        self.Number = Number
        self.Row = Row
        self.Column = Column
```

However, when trying to create an instance of the class,

```
H = Element(H, hydrogen, 1, 1, 1)
```

I get the error message

```
NameError: name 'H' is not defined
```

I suspect I'm using `__init__`  incorrectly, and if so, how can the mistake be corrected? Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is the second H? A string maybe?
H = Element(H, hydrogen, 1, 1, 1) in here you're trying to create an object and using itself in creation.

Comment: Please consider to use the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 3):

You are asking Python to pass in the values of two variables, named `H` and `hydrogen`, into the `Element` constructor:

```
Element(H, hydrogen, 1, 1, 1)
#       ^  ^^^^^^^^
```

Those variables are not defined. Did you mean to pass in strings instead perhaps? If so, use string literal syntax (quotes):

```
H = Element('H', 'hydrogen', 1, 1, 1)
```

Your use of `__init__` is otherwise fine. The traceback of the exception thrown would otherwise show that the method was actually invoked, and not point to the line calling `Element()`.

Comment: Oh, of course! What a stupid mistake >.< Thank you for spotting it!